# Pipe under outdoor faucet leaking. Any ideas?

Tags: leak, faucet, outdoor, spigot

[image: spigot]my outdoor faucet seems to be leaking. My gf wrapped it up with tape to try to reduce the flow (bless her) I don't know what pipe or piece seems to be connected under the actual spigot. Does anyone have an idea of a fix or replacement method?

Comment: A picture will help.  It sounds more like the garden hose or vacuum break leaking than the pipe from the house to the spigot.  If the first, then closing/shutting off the spigot should work.  If the second then need to shut off the water from inside and repair/replace that pipe and/or spigot.

Comment: Uploaded a picture for visual

Comment: Did you experience freezing weather recently?

Comment: The picture helps.  That is an easier repair than a straight pipe out from the the house.  Two wrenches and a replacement pipe/nipple and the water off is all you need.

Answer (score 6):

If the pipe itself is cracked and leaking, you replace the pipe itself, by unscrewing the spigot from the pipe and the pipe from the Tee fitting below. Such short sections of threaded pipe are called **pipe nipples**, and can be had in many different lengths from any hardware or plumbing supplier.

If it's leaking from the threads you may be able to stop the leak by tightening the pipe to whichever fitting joint is leaking, or by removing it, reapplying thread sealant (either tape or pipe dope) and reinstalling it.

If the pipe cracked because it froze, you might need to take preventative action to keep it from freezing again, as it is clearly just exposed to the outside air in a manner not suited to anywhere the temperatures ever drop below freezing.